# Disabling site generation and deploy in maven

Tags: java, maven-3, pom.xml

I have an existing maven project in which site goal is executed to generate and upload site to repository location. I need to disable only this site generation and deployment part from my maven release. How can I achieve that with minimal changes in my pom. In the pom, we are using maven-site-plugin version 3.4 and don't have any overrides defined (i.e. everything is default inherited for this plugin).

Comment: Can you not just make a new goal that is a copy of the regular one but leaving out the deployment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to find the solution for my problem. You can always override configurations for the plugins in your project POM file, which can override the configuration derived from parent POM file. You can use following user properties to disable site generation and site deployment:

- maven.site.skip=true (skips generating site)
- maven.site.deploy.skip=true (skips site deployment)

I inserted following in my pom and it worked fine:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
        <skipDeploy>true</skipDeploy>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can see in the effective POM that these overrides were merged with the plugin configuration derived from parent pom.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to create profiles for publishing, where you will parse the profile as a parameter when you need to execute the maven project to publish. 
Check [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for the documentation.